# Celery and RabbitMQ timeouts and connection resets

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.6.0 and Celery 3.1.20 on a Windows 10 machine in a Django application. Everything is running on the same computer. I've configured Celery to Acknowledge Late (`CELERY_ACKS_LATE=True`) and now I'm getting connection problems.

I start the Celery worker, and after 50-60 seconds of handling tasks each worker thread fails with the following message:

> Couldn't ack ###, reason:ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)

(### is the number of the task)

When I look at the RabbitMQ logs I see this:

> =INFO REPORT==== 10-Feb-2016::22:16:16 ===
>   accepting AMQP connection <0.247.0> (127.0.0.1:55372 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
>
> =INFO REPORT==== 10-Feb-2016::22:16:16 ===
>   accepting AMQP connection <0.254.0> (127.0.0.1:55373 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 10-Feb-2016::22:17:14 ===
>   closing AMQP connection <0.247.0> (127.0.0.1:55372 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
>   {writer,send_failed,{error,timeout}}

The error occurs exactly when the Celery workers are getting their connection reset.

I thought this was an AMQP Heartbeat issue, so I've added `BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 15` to my Celery settings, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out by chance?

Comment: In my case, I had the port at the end of the broker url. Removing the port resolved it. I think the port is handled automatically by celery and since broker may be running on a number of ports depending on availability, hard coding a port is not ideal.

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar issue with Celery on Windows with long running
tasks with concurrency=1. The following configuration finally worked for
me:

```
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

I also started the celery worker daemon with the -Ofair option:

```
celery -A test worker -l info -Ofair
```

In my limited understanding, CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER sets the number
of messages that sit in the queue of a specific Celery worker. By
default it is set to 4. If you set it to 1, each worker will only
consume one message and complete the task before it consumes another
message. I was having issues with long-running task because the
connection to RabbitMQ was consistently lost in the middle of the long task, but
then the task was re-attempted if any other message/tasks were waiting
in the celery queue.

The following option was also specific to my situation:

```
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
```

Setting concurrency to 1 made sense for me because I had long running
tasks that needed a large amount of RAM so they each needed to run solo.

Comment: Thanks for these tips. There's really nothing else out there that addresses this exact issue that I could find. I have the exact same ConnectionResetError as @zmbq . I am on Windows and also have concurrency pool of `solo`. I am pulling data from the Adwords API.

Comment: Since this posted answer, Windows support for Celery has been dropped, so take any suggestion here with a grain of salt.

Comment: Tried this on windows, but still facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

@bbaker solution with `CELERY_ACKS_LATE` (which is `task_acks_late` in celery 4x) itself did not work for me. My workers are in Kubernetes pods and must be run with `--pool solo` and each task takes 30-60s.

I solved it by including `broker_heartbeat=0`

```
broker_pool_limit = None
task_acks_late = True
broker_heartbeat = 0
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```